# Python: How to create concatenated string from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to pass from a dictionary, for example:

```
defaultdict(int, {'A': 5, 'B': 4, 'C': 4})
```

to a list like this:

`'A5B4C4'`

Is there any short and clever way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
''.join(k+str(v) for k,v in d.items())
# 'A5B4C4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = defaultdict(int, {'A': 5, 'B': 4, 'C': 4})
yourstring = ''.join(str(e) for t in d.items() for e in t)
```

Comment: Although this may be a valid answer, it is good to provide some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is using `reduce` function from `functools`

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(lambda a, b: a + str(b[0]) + str(b[1]), mydict.items(), ''))
>>>'A5B4C4'
# reduce takes 3 params (2 required and an optional initializer which is 3rd parameter '' )
```